# Karate Framework how can i create new sentence

Tags: karate

Hi i want to create new sentence with karate

```
** And request Req
** When method get
** Then status 200
```

I want to create these sentences as a single sentence.
Can something like this be done?

Answer (score 0):

No, something like this cannot be done.